# Use link function in directives to append different HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/o76hxj69/1/)

I have two buttons. When pressed it displays a modal, with som text. But I also want to add some html dynamically depending on which button is pressed.

I have tried both `$observe` and `$watch` methods, but I'm having problems making it work.

here is my code.

```
angular.module('TM', [])

.controller('protocolCtrl', function(){
    this.text = 'Now looking at the protocol part';
    this.modalId = 'protocolModal';
})

.controller('categoryCtrl', function(){
    this.text = 'Now looking at the category part';
    this.modalId = "categoryModal";
})

.directive('modalDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ctrl: '=',
            modalId: '@',
        },
        template:  ['<div id="{{modalId}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">', 
                      '<div class="modal-dialog">',
                        '<div class="modal-content">',
                        '<div class="modal-header">',
                        '<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>',
                        '</div>',
                        '<div class="modal-body">',
                        '<p> {{ ctrl.text }} </p>',
                        '</div>',
                        '<div class="modal-footer">',
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>',
                        '</div>',
                        '</div>', 
                        '</div>',
                        '</div>'].join(''),
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.$observe('modalId', function(){
                var modal = element.find('#{{modalId}}');
                if(modal == 'protocolModal'){
                    element.find('#{{modalId}}').append('<div>this is a protocol test...</div>');
                } else {
                    element.find('#{{modalId}}').append('<div>this is a category test...</div>');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need to manually `$watch` or `$observe`. If the template is controlled by `$scope.modalId`, then use `ng-if` to select what is being displayed, for example: `<div ng-if="modalId === 'protocolModal'">protocol test</div> <div ng-if="modalId === 'categoryModal'">category</div>`.

Comment: @NewDev hm, I'll try that as well. But I'd really appreciate it if you could show me what I would need to change in my fiddle to get it working with either `$observe` or `$watch` as well :)

Comment: I don't think there is `element.$observe` - there is `attrs.$observe` and `scope.$watch`. Anyway, here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/L0jns64m/

Comment: @NewDev you are absolutely right - thank you very much. You can just post this as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is `element.$observe` - there is `attrs.$observe` and `scope.$watch`. You already have `modelId` on the scope, so let's use that.

Also, instead of the wonky `.find` by id, inject an element as a placeholder for the template and `replaceWith` it accordingly:

```
template: '<div id="{{modalId}}">\
             ...\
             <div class="modal-body">\
               <template-placeholder></template-placeholder>\
             </div>\
           </div>",
link: function(scope, element){
  // ...

  var unwatch = scope.$watch("modalId", function(val){
    var placeholder = element.find('template-placeholder');
    if(val == 'protocolModal'){
       placeholder.replaceWith('<div>this is a protocol test...</div>');
    } else {
      placeholder.replaceWith('<div>this is a category test...</div>');
    }

    unwatch(); // seems like you don't really need to set it again
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See i updated your [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/o76hxj69/3/)

> Use **attr** in link function. because you already given attribute to
>   your html i.e: **modal-id="{{pctrl.modalId}}**

```
 <modal-directive ctrl="pctrl" modal-id="{{pctrl.modalId}}"></modal-directive>
```

---

```
  if(attrs.modalId == 'protocolModal'){
     element.find('#{{modalId}}').append('<div>this is a protocol test...</div>');
  } else {
     element.find('#{{modalId}}').append('<div>this is a category test...</div>');
  }
```

**Edit :**

use **$timeout**

```
$timeout(function () {

                if (attrs.modalId == 'protocolModal') {
                    element.find('#' + attrs.modalId).append('<div>this is a protocol test...</div>');
                } else {
                    element.find('#' + attrs.modalId).append('<div>this is a category test...</div>');
                }

            }, 1000)
```

> Now why **$timeout** because you are applying template and and at same
>   time your link function append your div so it will not apply your div
>    .So first apply template and then in template append your div

---

And if you want to show that div in popup content the use this selector.
see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/o76hxj69/6/

```
element.find('#'+attrs.modalId +' .modal-body').append('<div>this is a protocol test...</div>');
```

Comment: @Nilzone- have you checked fiddle ? https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/o76hxj69/3/

Comment: yes I have - and the divs I'm trying to append doesn't show up in the modal

Comment: @Nilzone- i updated my answer see this https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/o76hxj69/5/  you can see in inspect it is added your div

Comment: @Nilzone- https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/o76hxj69/6/ see this both update fiddel and let me know .

Answer (score 0):

If your two DOM structure diverses, you can consider using two different templates depending on some parameter value.

[`templateUrl` can be specified as a function](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), such as:

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
    .controller('ProfileCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        name: 'Elit'
    };
}])
    .directive('profile', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: function (elem, attrs) {
            return 'style-' + attrs.color + '.html';
        }
    };
}]);
```

And use the directive as:

```
<div ng-app="Joy" id="play-ground" ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
    <div profile color="red"></div>
    <div profile color="green"></div>
</div>
```

In this case, if the `color` is `red`, the directive will load template from `style-red.html`. Otherwise from `style-green.html`.

In your case, you might maintain a flag in the outside controller. Clicking either button will change this flag value and pass in to the directive. The directive will load different templates accordingly.